# Jquery ajax only want to save 1 value to a variable to use later Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

Ok. So I've finally figured out how to get a JSON Get request, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use the information I get back. I've got 9 items in the array, but I only care about 1 of the values. I'm trying to get the id: value and store it in a variable to use later. I know I currently have no attempt at doing the storing bit in the code - I've tried so many options, I reverted the code back to where it would at least get the array.

Here is the ajax code:

```
 var childSection;
        var url = "https://myurl.com";
        $.ajax({
    'async': true,
    'type': "GET",
    'global': false,
    'dataType': 'JSON',
    'data': JSON.stringify(childSection),
    'contentType': "application/json",
    'url': url,
    'success': function (data) {
        childSection = data;
        return childSection;  
    }
```

Comment: Picture doesnt work, link is broken.

Comment: Assuming the picture is of the `data` object, I think `childSection = data[0].id` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it's just a picture of the array, but I can't upload pics yet :P I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the "success" property, you have a function which is receiving the `data`.  You can take `data` and access the node that you want to save.  Let's say the node in question is called `wutangclan`, you can access it like so: `data.wutangclan`.

If you want to be able to get to `data.wutangclan` outside of the success function, there are several ways, but basically you want to assign it to a variable that was created outside of the success function.

Also, another way to do this is like so:

```
// since I defined this in the global scope, I can access it later inside the done function
var myGlobalVariable;

var request = $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: "GET",
          data: {
              yourdata: the_value_to_send
          },
          dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
          myGlobalVariable = data.wutangclan
        }
```